# Render JSON from controller method

Tags: lucee, fw1, commandbox

I'm on FW/1 4.2. The documentation states the following:

You can return data directly to the caller, bypassing views and layouts, using the renderData() function.

```
variables.fw.renderData().data( resultData ).type( contentType );
```

When I attempt to use variables.fw.renderData() in my controller function, I get the following error:

> Component [controllers.notifications] has no accessible Member with name [fw]

If I dump the variables scope, the only thing in it is the controller methods themselves. There is no fw object in the variables scope. I installed FW/1 using the commandbox CLI.

Everything else appears to be working fine (routing/etc). Why is the fw object not available to my controllers?

Comment: Is `variables.fw` defined in the component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to define `variables.fw` to the component scope.

```
public any function init( fw ){
    variables.fw = fw;
    return this;
}
```

`Variables` inside a component behaves different than in regular `cfm` pages. Inside a component `variables` scope holds the properties of the components such as member functions and other defined properties.